# how to make text resize over different screen sizes in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout, mobile-application

I want to make a flutter app for different mobile screen sizes. I want to know how to take care of text size over different devices. I have tried to use **media query** like `textSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.022` , but it doesn't take care of it that well. Text looks good on some phones but is either over or undersized and shabby on different screens. Please help :(, Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you try this https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Comment: yes, no much change, text still appears large on small dpi devices like 640 dpi